# php - asort not working for timestamp array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, timestamp

I am trying to sort an array having the timestamp values as elements into ascending order, for this purpose I tried `asort` but looks like it is not working for me. Below is the sample array I have been trying. Can anyone please help me?

```
    array() { 
[74]=> int(1467295200)
[75]=> int(1467381600)
[76]=> int(1467468000)
[77]=> int(1467554400)
[48]=> int(1467639000)
[78]=> int(1467640800)
[79]=> int(1467727200)
[36]=> int(1468243800)
[49]=> int(1468243800)
[30]=> int(1468285200)
[24]=> int(1468287000)
[18]=> int(1468288800)
[12]=> int(1468290600)
[6]=> int(1468292400)
[37]=> int(1468330200)
[31]=> int(1468458000)
[25]=> int(1468459800)
[19]=> int(1468461600)
[13]=> int(1468463400)
[7]=> int(1468465200)
[38]=> int(1468503000)
[32]=> int(1468544400)
[26]=> int(1468546200)
[20]=> int(1468548000)
[14]=> int(1468549800)
[8]=> int(1468551600)
[39]=> int(1468589400)
}
```

Comment: can you show your code with `asort`?

Comment: But it works! Yours array elements values are in ascending order :)
also, you can try numeric sort `asort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)`

Comment: Thanks @rokas: I just noticed that I messed up with my code at some other part where I have to display the sorted array and that is where I misunderstood that `asort` is not working. Anyways, I have added `SORT_NUMERIC` too.